# How to replace default jtable column values when exporting rows to Excel - Java

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable, apache-poi

```
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                XSSFRow newRow = sheet1.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    XSSFCell excelCell = newRow.createCell((short) j);
                    if (j == model.getColumnCount() - 1) {
                        JLabel excelJL = (JLabel) model.getValueAt(i, j);
                        ImageIcon excelImageIcon = (ImageIcon) excelJL.getIcon();
                        String imagePath = excelImageIcon.getDescription();
                        //[i][j] = imagePath;
                    }

                        excelCell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());

                }
            }
```

Am exporting data from jtable to excel, How go i set *imagePath* String to be set in excel column replacing the last jtable column. In this case the last column outputs jlabel model instead of outputting image path. I have got a way to extract the image path, and i want to replace that column with new data which is image path string and its stored in "imagePath" variable

Answer (score 0):

```
            //Loop through the jtable columns and rows to get its values
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                XSSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);

                    //Change the image column to output image path
                    //Fourth column contains images
                    if (j == model.getColumnCount() - 1) {
                        JLabel excelJL = (JLabel) model.getValueAt(i, j);
                        ImageIcon excelImageIcon = (ImageIcon) excelJL.getIcon();
                        //Image Name Is Stored In ImageIcons Description First set it And Then Retrieve it.
                        excelImagePath = excelImageIcon.getDescription();
                    }

                    excelCell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                    if (excelCell.getColumnIndex() == model.getColumnCount() - 1) {
                        excelCell.setCellValue(excelImagePath);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Am changing the last column. So this code changes all column values to the value of passed argument. In my case am displaying image paths.